# Scrolling Text Pane JFrame Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, keylistener

I'm trying to create a sort of log of all the keys hit, at the moment I just need to figure out how to either:

Link the position of the "text" to the scroll bar to the right

OR

Add a different component which is suited better to hold large amounts of multiple line text.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
public class MacroMakerGui extends JFrame {

public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static JPanel contentPane;
public static JTextField textField = new JTextField();;
public static MacroKeyListener keylistener = new MacroKeyListener(textField);

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MacroMakerGui frame = new MacroMakerGui();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MacroMakerGui() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 126, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Record Macro");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 220, 99, 30);

    contentPane.add(btnNewButton, null);

    textField.setBounds(10, 189, 99, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setBounds(10, 11, 84, 153);
    contentPane.add(editorPane);

    JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
    scrollBar.setBounds(93, 11, 17, 153);
    contentPane.add(scrollBar);

    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            btnNewButton.addKeyListener(keylistener);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: You may also want to have a look at 
[How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of JScrollBar, use JScrollPanel. Add that to the contentPane, and add your editorPane as a chiled of the JScrollPanel.